# Are there any pairs of integers that are divisible by the same primes such that adding $1$ or $2$ also keeps them divisible by the same primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587564/are-there-finitely-many-pairs-of-integers-that-are-divisible-by-the-same-primes) shows that there are infinitely many pairs of integers $(m, n)$ such that $m$ and $n$ have the same prime factors, and $m+1$ and $n+1$ also have the same prime factors. Are there any such pairs of integers with that have the same prime factors such that $m+1$ and $n+1$ have the same prime factors, and $m+2$ and $n+2$ also have the same prime factors? If so, are there infinitely many such pairs?

Comment: related : [Uniqueness or non uniqueness of a pair of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719749/uniqueness-or-non-uniqueness-of-a-pair-of-natural-numbers)

Comment: I do not think that this is a duplicate since it asks for the existence of a pair with a stronger property.

Comment: For $m,n\le 10^7$ there is no such pair.